# how check for null value using ng-if with ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs

I have error in this code I try tyo check for null value using ng-if wtih ng-repeat

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6" ng-repeat="player in  PlayerData">
     <div class="club-sport">
          <a href="../../Player/PlayerProfile/{{player['ID']}}" target="_blank">
               <img src="../../images/Players/{{player['ProfileImage']}}" class="player-img">
               <h4> {{player['Name']}}   </h4>
                <div class="border-bottom"></div>
                <p> {{player['ClubName']}}  </p>
           </a>
     </div>
     <div class="no-result" ng-if="!player">
           <p> لا يوجد لاعبين </p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Player is an object. ng-repeat won't iterate over something if it's not there, so check to see that a property is there if one may be missing

Comment: I think this : `<div class="no-result" ng-if="!player">
                        <p> لا يوجد لاعبين </p>
                    </div>` should be out of the ngRepeat and the ngIf should be like this : `ng-if="!PlayerData"`

Answer (score 0):

Just use `ng-if="player['Name']"` if the `Name` property is null this will return false

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6" ng-repeat="player in  PlayerData">
    <div class="club-sport">
       <a href="../../Player/PlayerProfile/{{player['ID']}}" target="_blank">
          <img src="../../images/Players/{{player['ProfileImage']}}" class="player-img">
          <h4  ng-if="player['ClubName']" > {{player['Name']}} </h4>
          <div class="border-bottom"></div>
          <p ng-if="player['ClubName']"> {{player['ClubName']}} </p>
       </a>
   </div>
   <div class="no-result" ng-if="!player">
       <p> لا يوجد لاعبين </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

first thank you for your interest 
i try update code and make

لا يوجد لاعبين

out of the ngrepeat but message "لا يوجد لاعبين" show with me in two cases whta's wrong in this case

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6" ng-repeat="player in  PlayerData">
                <div class="club-sport" ng-if="player.Name">
                    <a href="../../Player/PlayerProfile/{{player['ID']}}" target="_blank">
                        <img src="../../images/Players/{{player['ProfileImage']}}" class="player-img">
                        <h4> {{player['Name']}}   </h4>
                        <div class="border-bottom"></div>
                        <p> {{player['ClubName']}}  </p>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="no-result" ng-if="!player.Name">
                <p> لا يوجد لاعبين </p>
            </div>
```

Comment: please update code or respond to comment. don't make an answer that's just an update or comment.

Answer (score 0):

Since player is an object it will exist even if it doesn't have properties.  A better way to do this is to check if a specific property exists.  In this case I am checking if the 'Name' property exists.

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6" ng-repeat="player in  PlayerData">
     <div class="club-sport">
          <a href="../../Player/PlayerProfile/{{player['ID']}}" target="_blank">
               <img src="../../images/Players/{{player['ProfileImage']}}" class="player-img">
               <h4> {{player['Name']}}   </h4>
                <div class="border-bottom"></div>
                <p> {{player['ClubName']}}  </p>
           </a>
     </div>
     <div class="no-result" ng-if="!player['Name']">
           <p> لا يوجد لاعبين </p>
     </div>
</div>
```